# sql statement ignored and from key word not found

Tags: sql, oracle, function, plsql, ora-00923

This results in an `ORA-00923: From keyword not found` error:

```
create or replace function gr_pay_hrly (p_wage_rate IN Number, 
                                        p_hrs_worked In number)
Return Number IS

  t_wage pay_history.wage_rate%type;
  t_hours pay_history.hrs_worked%type;
  t_gross_pay number(10,2);

BEGIN

  select wage_rate into t_wage, 
         hrs_worked into t_hours
    from pay_history
   where wage_rate = p_wage_rate
     and hrs_worked = p_hrs_worked;

  IF t_hours >= 40 THEN
    t_gross_pay := (((t_hours - 40) * t_wage) * 1.5);
  ELSE
    t_gross_pay := t_hours * t_wage;
  END IF;

  RETURN t_gross_pay;

  END;
  /
```

Comment: The logic of this seems wack.  You are selecting and manipulating values which are exactly the same value as the parameters passed in so what is the point of the query?  Why not just do the math on the parameter values?  What happens if more than one record is selected?

Comment: Also, if I worked 42 hours I would expect to be paid for 43 hours not 3.  That is, surely GROSS_PAY should equal `((40 * wage_rate) + (((hours_worked-40) * wage_rate) * 1.5))`

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is the `INTO` clause -- it's only declared once in a statement:

```
SELECT ph.wage_rate,
       ph.hrs_worked
  INTO t_wage, t_hours
  FROM PAY_HISTORY ph
 WHERE ph.wage_rate = p_wage_rate
   AND ph.hrs_worked = p_hrs_worked;
```

The population of variables is based on the order of the columns declared in the SELECT clause.

### Full re-write:

If you subtract 40 from the `hours_worked` with is also 40, you'll just be multiplying by zero.  And you want to add the straight time payout to the overtime...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION gr_pay_hrly (p_wage_rate IN NUMBER, 
                                        p_hrs_worked IN NUMBER)
RETURN NUMBER IS

  t_gross_pay NUMBER(10,2);

BEGIN

  SELECT CASE 
           WHEN ph.hrs_worked > 40 THEN ((ph.hrs_worked - (ph.hrs_worked - 40)) * ph.wage_rate) + (ph.hrs_worked - 40) * ph.wage_rate * 1.5
           WHEN ph.hrs_worked <= 40 THEN ph.hrs_worked * ph.wage_rate
           ELSE 0
         END
    INTO t_gross_pay
    FROM PAY_HISTORY ph
   WHERE ph.wage_rate = p_wage_rate
     AND ph.hrs_worked = p_hrs_worked;

  RETURN t_gross_pay;

END;
```